# Matrix vector multiplication of trigonometric functions

Tags: matrix, algebraic-manipulation

My problem is to show the expressions in the photo (from [this book](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=kYPCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA38)) are equivalent using Mathematica.  The code below is not giving the desired results.  What I have so far should reduce to the column vector `{psidot, phidot, thetadot}`, but that's not what is happening.

The results are not being simplified (e.g. `Sin[phi]^2 + Cos[phi]^2 == 1`), and I have the issue of dividing by `Sin[theta]`.  The way I have it, this is not factored from the matrix, but instead the matrix is multiplied by `Csc[theta]`.  Any help would be appreciated--obviously a first-time Mathematica user.

[image: screenshot]
Thank you,
Rick

```
a = {{Sin[theta].Sin[phi], 0, Cos[phi]}, {Sin[theta].Cos[phi], 
0, -Sin[phi]}, {Cos[theta], 1, 0}};

b = {{Sin[phi], Cos[phi], 0}, {-Sin[phi].Cos[theta], -Cos[phi].Cos[theta], 
Sin[theta]}, {Cos[phi].Sin[theta], -Sin[phi].Sin[theta], 0}};

omega = {wx, wy, wz};

angles = {psidot, phidot, thetadot};

aa = a.angles;
baa = b.aa;
part1 = 1/Sin[theta].baa;
TrigReduce[part1];
MatrixForm[part1] here
```

Comment: The `.` is used for dot products between vectors. You want to use `*` for multiplication where it applies.  Also, I don't see a picture.

Comment: Next time, if you're presenting equations from a book or a paper, please mention said book or paper. I have done it for you this time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as March said, you have used wrong notations for . and *

```
Clear["Global`*"];

a = {{Sin[theta] Sin[phi], 0, Cos[phi]}, 
     {Sin[theta] Cos[phi], 0, -Sin[phi]}, 
     {Cos[theta], 1, 0}};

b = {{Sin[phi], Cos[phi], 0}, 
     {-Sin[phi] Cos[theta], -Cos[phi] Cos[theta], Sin[theta]}, 
     {Cos[phi] Sin[theta], -Sin[phi] Sin[theta], 0}
     };

omega   = {wx, wy, wz};
angles  = {psidot, phidot, thetadot};
(aa = a.angles) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
baa   = b.aa;
part1 = 1/Sin[theta]*baa;

TrigReduce[part1] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

Nasser and march already addressed the problem with your initial attempt. I'll present a way to transform your simultaneous equations into the matrix-vector format.

In particular, `CoefficientArrays[]` is the useful function here. Start with the equations in 3.5-2 of [Thomson's book](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=kYPCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA38):

```
eqs = {\[FormalPsi] == (ωx Sin[φ] + ωy Cos[φ])/Sin[θ],
       \[FormalCurlyPhi] == ωz - (Cos[θ]/Sin[θ])(ωx Sin[φ] + ωy Cos[φ]),
       \[FormalTheta] == ωx Cos[φ] - ωy Sin[φ]};
```

(Note that I have used [formal Greek letters](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MathematicalAndOtherNotation.html#173509264) to represent the dotted variables, and `ωx, ωy, ωz` to represent $\omega_x,\omega_y,\omega_z$. They look funny here, but they should display as expected if you paste the code above into a *Mathematica* notebook.)

Then,

```
{vc, mc} = Normal[CoefficientArrays[eqs, {ωx, ωy, ωz}]];
mc = -mc;
```

`vc` should now contain the variables $\dot{\psi},\dot{\varphi},\dot{\theta}$:

```
vc
   {\[FormalPsi], \[FormalCurlyPhi], \[FormalTheta]}
```

[image: screenshot]

and `mc` should yield the expected matrix:

```
mc
   {{Csc[θ] Sin[φ], Cos[φ] Csc[θ], 0},
    {-Cot[θ] Sin[φ], -Cos[φ] Cot[θ], 1},
    {Cos[φ], -Sin[φ], 0}}
```

If you want to match the form displayed in the book for equation 3.5-4:

[image: formatted matrix]

but I ***do not encourage*** using this pretty format except for display purposes, since you won't be able to use it for further manipulations.

Then, to get the coefficient matrix in equation 3.5-3, use `Inverse[]`:

```
Inverse[mc] // Simplify
   {{Sin[θ] Sin[φ], 0, Cos[φ]},
    {Cos[φ] Sin[θ], 0, -Sin[φ]},
    {Cos[θ], 1, 0}}
```

[image: formatted inverse]

Comment: Thank you.  I will remember to cite my sources in the future, and will work on incorporating what you have here as I gain experience with Mathematica.